# Concisely creating an IDictionary<_,obj>

Tags: f#

Is there a shorter way of creating an `IDictionary<_,obj>`, possibly without boxing every value? This is what I have.

```
let values =
  [ "a", box 1
    "b", box "foo"
    "c", box true ]
  |> dict
```

`Dictionary<_,obj>.Add` can be called without boxing, but I couldn't figure out a way to use it that's shorter than what I have.

I'm hoping for something other than defining a boxing operator.

#### EDIT

Based on Brian's suggestion, here's one way to do it, but it has its own problems.

```
let values =
  Seq.zip ["a"; "b"; "c"] ([1; "foo"; true] : obj list) |> dict
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a solution, following kvb's suggestion (probably the most concise, and clearest, so far):

```
let inline (=>) a b = a, box b

let values =
  [ "a" => 1
    "b" => "foo"
    "c" => true ]
  |> dict
```

Comment: Yes, this is very nice, feel free to switch your accepted answer!

Comment: I'm giving kvb a chance to post it. I can't accept my own answer for two days anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the slickest thing I was able to whip up. It has more characters than your boxing version, but possibly feels a little less dirty. Note that the `^` is right-associative (it's the string concat operator inherited from ocaml), which lets it work like `::`, and it has stronger precedence than `,`, which is why the parenthesis are needed around the tuples.

```
let inline (^+) (x1:'a,x2:'b) (xl:('a*obj) list) = 
    (x1,box x2)::xl

let values =
  ("a", 1) ^+  ("b", "foo") ^+ ("c", true) ^+ []
  |> dict
```

Comment: Is there something with lower precedence than `,` so we can omit the parens?

Comment: The only custom operator permitted with lower precedence than `,` that I could find is `:=` (and also happens to be right-associative) but that is already taken by `ref` set (and variations leading with `:` or `:=` are all invalid, it has to be exactly `:=`)

Comment: It's a nice solution, and probably as good as it's going to get. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I remember struggling over this a while back so when you posted this question my first instinct was "Nope!". This nifty solution was just a sudden flash of inspiration (madness?).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem in FsSql and I just tucked away boxing in a function:

```
let inline T (a,b) = a, box b
let values = dict [T("a",1); T("b","foo"); T("c",true)]
```

Comment: This requires the same number of extra chars (`T()`) as `box`. Actually, it's one shorter is you count the space after `box`.

Comment: @Daniel: is this about golfing? I just find this more convenient than boxing each value.

Comment: Not really. I was just wondering what the benefit is since the keystrokes are virtually the same.

Comment: @Daniel: less keystrokes != better. I find this mentally easier, though of course YMMV.

Comment: @Daniel: If you're really concerned about keystrokes, you could also use an operator in place of `T`, in which case the operator would take the place of the comma, rather than adding to the total.

Comment: @Mauricio, don't you mean `less keystrokes <> better`?

Comment: @Mauricio: I'm working on a large project and I'll be typing this a lot, so yes `less keystrokes = much better`.

Comment: @Daniel: at this level, with this difference in keystrokes, I beg to differ.

Comment: @kvb: That's probably the best idea yet. I posted it as an answer, but if you want to post it, I'll be glad to delete mine and accept yours.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another "solution" which is inspired from Brian's suggestion but it uses reflection so there is a time and safety cost.

```
let unboxPair (pair:obj) =
    let ty = pair.GetType()
    let x = ty.GetProperty("Item1").GetValue(pair,null) :?> string
    let y = ty.GetProperty("Item2").GetValue(pair,null)
    x,y

let unboxPairs (pairs:obj list) =
  pairs |> List.map unboxPair  

let values =
  unboxPairs
    ["a", 1
     "b", "foo"
     "c", true]
  |> dict
```

Answer (score 1):

A variation of Stephen's idea:

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic

type Dictionary<'a,'b> with
  member this.Add([<ParamArray>] args:obj[]) =
    match args.Length with
    | n when n % 2 = 0 ->
      for i in 1..2..(n-1) do
        this.Add(unbox args.[i-1], unbox args.[i])
    | _ -> invalidArg "args" "even number of elements required"

let d = Dictionary<string,obj>()
d.Add(
  "a", 1,
  "b", "foo",
  "c", true
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution, simply define a bunch of overloaded extension members on `Dictionary<'a,'b>`:

```
open System.Collections.Generic
type Dictionary<'a,'b> with
    member this.Add(x1,y1,x2,y2) =
        this.Add(x1,y1)
        this.Add(x2,y2)
    member this.Add(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3) =
        this.Add(x1,y1,x2,y2)
        this.Add(x3,y3)
    member this.Add(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4) =
        this.Add(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3)
        this.Add(x4,y4)
    member this.Add(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4,x5,y5) =
        this.Add(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4)
        this.Add(x5,y5)
    member this.Add(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4,x5,y5,x6,y6) =
        this.Add(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4,x5,y5)
        this.Add(x6,y6)
    //etc.

let values = 
    let d = Dictionary<_,obj>()
    d.Add("a", 1, 
          "b", "foo", 
          "c", true)
    d
```

Of course `values` here is *not* immutable like in your question, but I'm sure you could employ the same strategy in that goal.

Comment: You could use `ParamArray` instead of overloads. I posted an answer with an example.

Comment: Yeah, then it's kind of a hybrid between this answer and my reflection answer, since you lose type safety on the key.

Answer (score -1):

```
let v : (string*obj) list = [...]
let values = dict v
```

Is one way, the type signature on the left of the list literal will auto-upcast each element.

Comment: It gives the error `expected to have type obj`. This was the first thing I tried.

Comment: While this trick would work for a `obj list`, it doesn't work for `(string*obj) list` since `string*int` is not a subclass of `string*obj` for example (and F# doesn't support any kind of covariance, though this wouldn't work in C# either, since generic covariance only works in .NET on interfaces and delegates, and the Tuple series of classes don't implement any kind of ITuple interface).

Comment: Ah, oops, that's what I get typing answers on my phone away from a machine  :)