# F#: combining together discriminated unions and class hierarchies?

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

Let's say I have a significant class hierarchy:

```
Tag
    ControlFlowTag
        IfTag
        ForTag
    JumpTag
    HTMLTag
        DivTag
```

and I want to make a list interspersed with these and strings.

```
let MyList = [tagA, tagB, "some text", tagC]
```

and I thought I could discriminated union it

```
type Node = 
    | Tag of Tag
    | String of String

let MyList: list<Node> = [tagA, tagB, "some text", tagC]
```

but alas, it doesn't work without

```
let MyList: list<Node> = [Tag tagA, Tag tagB, String "some text", Tag tagC]
```

Obviously the Tag and String described in Node are orthogonal and separate from the existing Tag/String classes. Mousing over gives me the types as `Node.Tag` and `Node.String`, which isn't what I want.

What I have now is a function `t` which creates a `StringTag` which inherits from `Tag`, giving me

```
let MyList : list<Tag> = [tagA, tagB, t"some text", tagC]
```

which is pretty nice, but the extra `t` adds to the visual noise. What I actually want is a strongly typed "list of two different types" which I could work with using `match` statements. I thought that was the point of Discriminated Unions, but their inability to use existing type hierarchies is a problem, since the existing hierarchy (in this case `Tag`) is complex enough I think a full OO-inheritence approach to that subset of types is clearer than a pure Discriminated Union approach

One option is to just make it a list of `obj` and cast everything before/during the `match`, but that's not really very nice. Are there any other approaches?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you had two different DUs, say

```
type Node = 
  | Tag of Tag
  | String of String
```

and

```
type Foo = 
  | Bar of Tag
  | Name of String
```

how would the compiler know of which type the following list is?

```
[tagA; tagB; "some text"; tagC]
```

As svick said, the discriminator is necessary. If you use classes instead you'll need to upcast to the base type, so I'm not sure you save on keystrokes.

If you're working with dictionaries, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407873/concisely-creating-an-idictionary-obj/7410842#7410842) is a nice option to reduce the syntactic noise of boxing. Maybe you can do something similar for lists.

Comment: Or even: `type Node = Bar of Tag | Foo of Tag`

Answer (score 8):

I don't know how helpful this is, but you can use Active Patterns to match a class hierarchy in a DU-like fashion if appropriate.

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type Animal() =
    abstract Talk : string

type Cat() =
    inherit Animal()
    override this.Talk = "Meow"

type Dog() =
    inherit Animal()
    override this.Talk = "Woof"

type SuperCat(s) =
    inherit Cat()
    override this.Talk = s

let animals : list<Animal> = 
    [Dog(); Cat(); SuperCat("MEOW")]

let (|SCSaid|_|) (a:Animal) =    // Active Pattern
    match a with
    | :? SuperCat as sc -> Some sc.Talk 
    | _ -> None

for a in animals do
    match a with
    | :? Dog -> printfn "dog"    
    | SCSaid s -> printfn "SuperCat said %s" s // looks like DU
    | _ -> printfn "other"
//dog
//other
//SuperCat said MEOW
```

Answer (score 2):

Discriminated unions are just that – discriminated (unlike e.g. C unions). That means you have to always add the discriminator.

If this were C#, I would think about having an implicit conversion from `string` to `StringTag`. But since F# doesn't support implicit conversions, I think the second approach is your best bet. Although I would make the function's name more descriptive, not just `t`. Most of the time, it's better to write code that's easy to read, not code that's easy to write.